# add Point type to MySQL using TypeORM

Tags: mysql, typescript, coordinates, typeorm, point

I have a "coordinte" column in my database in MySQL that the type of it is point,
and I want to use TypeORM in order to add content to this column in MySQL.

I tried option 1 :
@Column({type: 'point',name: 'coordinate'})
coordinate!: string;

and then in the tests file:
const TEST_COORDINATE: string = "POINT(1 2)";

and I also tried option 2:
@Column({
type: 'point',name: 'coordinate',
})
coordinate!: Point;

and then in the tests file:
const TEST_COORDINATE: Point = {
type: 'Point',
coordinates: [1, 2]
};

none of them (and some other solutions I found online) worked

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).